# How to debug using Visual Studio on a remote Linux server using "double" ssh?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to connect to a Linux server for c++ development through Visual Studio for debugging purposes. The server is a computing cluster and works in the following way:

- You have a ssh portal let's say login@website.com where I use my username and password to log in.
- But then to actually run an application I need to do `ssh gpu-server` in the SSH terminal that I used to login. And then on this server I can run c++ applications that require the use of a gpu.

The problem I am facing with Visual Studio, is that I can set up the first server as a remote connection on the Connection Manager and it works perfectly. But I cannot Debug or compile anything on this server since it doesn't have a gpu (for my application I need a GPU). For this I need to do a second ssh. But I do not see how to do this with Visual Studio. I tried using a *before build event* on the configuration, but it just hanged when it does the command `ssh gpu-server`.

**How could I do this "double" ssh on Visual Studio?**

I cannot just connect directly to the second one since I am not an administrator on that cluster.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a very peculiar sort of constraints you have. Can't you just use your "second" machine as the primary since it has a GPU?

Comment: No I cannot, since it is a node on a computing cluster but the machine (the node) is not accesible unless you log in through the other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to setup a SSH tunnel so that visual studio can connect directly to your target machine.

For example if you are using Putty as your SSH client go to "Connection", "SSH", "Tunnels", set the "Source Port" to something like `8000` and the "Destination" to `gpu-server:22` select the type as "Local". Once you have opened the ssh session visual studio should be able to connect directly to `gpu-server` via `localhost:8000`.

Comment: This question is not related to SO. It would be nice to move such questions to the site which fits. Answering questions which are not related to SO feeds more and more abuse.

Comment: The solution may not be programming related but the question of "how do I debug in visual studio" definitely is

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I was to fast by seeing the thousands "how to connect via ssh..." today.

Comment: I agree with Alan, at first I was even expecting the solution to be with Putty, I thought I was missing some kind of hidden or obscure option on Visual Studio that could solve this. I have edited the question to make clear that it isn't general software related but Visual Studio related.
Thank you Alan for the answer. It really helped me.